# Тире в сложноподчинённом предложении

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, спп, тире

У Розенталя есть два примера постановки тире в сложноподчиненном предложении:

*Он, чтобы показать, что всё это знает и со всем согласен, что он далёк от каких-либо сомнений — тут же предложил свои услуги.*

*Зато мы приобрели опыт, а за опыт, как говорится, сколько ни заплати — не переплатишь.*

Тире якобы ставится как более выразительный знак. Но почему при этом запятая перед тире не ставится по общему правилу, чтобы закрыть придаточное предложение? В связи с этим возникает вопрос, ставить ли в данном случае запятую:

*Если ты сразу устроился в компанию своей мечты, где и функционал интересный, и платят щедро[,] — ты счастливчик.*

На мой взгляд, даже ставя тире, запятую перед ним следует поставить.

Answer (score 1):

*Если **ты** сразу устроился в компанию своей мечты, где и функционал интересный, и платят щедро, — **ты** счастливчик.*

Мне кажется, что запятая в этом предложении необходима на "законных" основаниях, потому что она закрывает придаточное предложение.
А вот тире может выступать здесь как *дополнительный знак* после запятой. Оно поставлено перед словом **ты**, которое повторяется для связи с дальнейшей частью предложения.
[Пунктуация. Тире. § 175](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/rules/158-tire)

Контекста нет, но если бы мне пришлось расставлять знаки препинания в этом предложении, то я бы логически выделила местоимение (с помощью тире):

**Если ты сразу устроился в компанию своей мечты, где и функционал интересный, и платят щедро, ты — счастливчик.**

Comment: Тире здесь может ставиться только из-за обилия запятых. Правило про дополнительный знак: «Тире ставится в качестве дополнительного знака после запятой перед словом, которое повторяется для того, чтобы связать с ним **новое предложение** (чаще **придаточное, усиливающее, дополняющее или развивающее главное предложение**) или **дальнейшую часть того же предложения**». Нам это правило не подходит, у нас чётко СПП с условным придаточным на первом месте и главным предложением на втором.

Comment: Совершенно верно. При _стандартной_ структуре предложение имело бы  такой вид: Ты счастливчик, если […] сразу устроился в компанию своей мечты, где и функционал интересный, и платят щедро (одно "ты" можно безболезненно опустить). При "обратной" структуре это невозможно. Обилие запятых?  Простите, но я его — этого обилия — здесь не вижу.

Answer (score 0):

Первый пример показывает предложение с **"перечислением придаточных частей"**. О постановке запятой можно и поспорить, но для анализа Вашего предложения этот пример не подходит.

Во втором примере тире поставлено **вместо** запятой из-за обилия запятых. Опять не Ваш случай.

У Вас тире и запятая ставятся по разным причинам.

**Если ты сразу устроился в компанию своей мечты, где и функционал интересный, и платят щедро, — ты счастливчик.**

Comment: Если упростить предложения, получится: "За опыт, сколько ни заплати, не переплатишь" и "Он, чтобы показать это, тут же предложил свои услуги". На мой взгляд, даже ставя перед продолжением главной части тире, запятая перед ним нужна.

Comment: С тем, что сравнение слегка некорректно, согласен.

Comment: "За опыт сколько ни ни заплати — не переплатишь." По-моему, никаких запятых не надо.   "Он, чтобы показать распространенное первое, распространенное второе, — тут же предложил свои услуги". По-моему, тут запятая и тире на "переломе" сложного   предложения. (§ 40. Запятая и тире в сложноподчиненном предложении)

Comment: А разве "Сколько ни заплати" не придаточное уступительное? "За опыт не переплатишь, сколько ни заплати". Во втором предложении перелома я не наблюдаю — для "перелома" необходимо бессоюзное предложение, а у нас СПП.

Comment: "За опыт не переплатишь, сколько ни заплати". Однако возможно и так: "Сколько ни заплати за опыт, не переплатишь." И здесь возможно тире вместо запятой. А у нас третий вариант, который, по-моему, ближе ко второму.

Comment: "В других случаях тире ставится после запятой, закрывающей придаточную часть, при «переломе» конструкции" (Розенталь). Речь о СПП.

Comment: Хорошо. А почему тогда в примере у Розенталя стоит только тире, то есть придаточная часть не закрывается запятой?

Comment: У меня нет объяснения.